# MognoDB Nodejs getting specific collection documents by ID

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I am trying to get a specific collection document from my database in node. I seem to be retrieving the entire list of documents in my "photos" collection. I've played around with it a few times, and was wondering if there is a simpler/better way to get the data instead of what I am attempting to do. All I am trying to do is get a photo with a specific ID and then just return that photo to the user.

Here is my code:

```
async function getPhoto(id) {

  const db = getDbReference();
  const collection = db.collection("photos")
  console.log({"id": id})
  
  const results = await collection
  .findOne(id)
  .toArray();
  return results
  
}

exports.getPhoto = getPhoto;
```

Photo endpoint file:

```
router.get('/:photoID', async (req, res, next) => {
  // const photoID = parseInt(req.params.photoID);
  
  try {
    const photo = await getPhoto(req.params.photoID)
    res.status(201).send(photo);


  }catch(err){
    console.error("--error", err);
    res.status(500).send({
      err: "Error fetching photo from DB. Try again later",
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `find` instead of `findOne`.

```
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

async function getPhoto(id) {

  const db = getDbReference();
  const collection = db.collection("photos")
  console.log({"id": id})
  
  const results = await collection.find({_id: new ObjectID(id)}).toArray();
  return results
}
```

**RECOMMENDATION:** You should check `mongoose` package for interacting with `mongoDB`. It will simplify your queries and it will allow you to create a Schema Models that will directly map to your Collections.

Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

Comment: Now I am just getting an empty array, like it didn't find anything with that ID almost. Here is my postman call: http://localhost:8000/photos/60903398deba3d377ca907d2 and here is my object in Mongo DB { "_id" : ObjectId("60903398deba3d377ca907d2"), "userid" : 2, "businessid" : 1, "caption" : "this is a weird photo" } Also, I will checkout Mongoose

Comment: It is in `localhost`. Only you can open it.

Comment: Yeah. It's strange that I am getting an empty array but a status of 201

Comment: I updated my answer. It is possibly that you need to send an ObjectId() and not a string. Can you try it again?

Comment: I am getting a reference Error ObjectId is not defined

Comment: You have to add the `ObjectID` from `mongodb` package. I updated my answer. Check if it works for you.